# How to retain data of 2 files together as well as find the difference among values

Tags: python, sql, excel

So here is the logic for finding out the difference and I have to merge the results in the format of the screenshot. I am trying to read 2 different files with certain unique ids which could match with the ids present in the second file. And I have to find out a solution to prepare a 3rd file containing the ids with its value in the first file and second file and also display the difference if any. If there is a new value then it should display either 0 or null in the respective cell value.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import xlrd 

df1_1 = pd.read_table('./first_file.txt', sep = '/t')
df1_1.to_excel('filename1.xlsx') 
df_first_file = pd.concat([df1_1['Column'].str.split('  ',expand=True)],axis=1)
df_new1 = df_first_file.to_excel('first_file1.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_table('./otherfile.txt', sep = '/t')
df1.to_excel('filename2.xlsx') 
df_otherfile = pd.concat([df1['Column'].str.split('  ',expand=True)],axis=1)
df_new2 = df_otherfile.to_excel('other_file1.xlsx')

df1 = pd.read_excel('./first_file1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('./other_file1.xlsx') 

print (df1)

df3= pd.DataFrame()
df3= df2  
mydict = dict()
mydict2 = dict()
for i in range(1,df2.shape[0]):
    for j in range(1,df1.shape[0]):
        if df2[0][i] == df1[0][j]: 
           mydict[df2[0][i]]= df2[2][j]

for i in range(df1.shape[0]): 
    if df1[0][i] in mydict :
        if str(df1[2][i]).find(',')!=-1 :
          a= df1[2][i].replace(',','')
        if str(mydict[df1[0][i]]).find(',')!=-1 :
           b= mydict[df1[0][i]].replace(',','') 
        if float(a) > float(b):
          mydict2[df1[0][i]]=df1[2][i]

arr=[]
arr.append("NULL")

for i in range(1,df3.shape[0]):
    if df3[0][i] in mydict2 :
        if str(df3[2][i]).find(',')!=-1 :               
            a= df3[2][i].replace(',','')
        else :
            a= df3[2][i]
        if str(mydict2[df3[0][i]]).find(',')!=-1 :
            b= mydict2[df3[0][i]].replace(',','')
        else:
            b=mydict2[df3[0][i]]
        arr.append(max(float(a),float(b))-min(float(a),float(b)))
    else :
        arr.append(0.0)

df3['CHANGE']=arr
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('./final.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1') 
writer.save()
```

[image]

Using merge function will work here or not I am still figuring out.

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me:
print (df1)
print(df2)
merge_results = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='IDNUMBER', how='outer', indicator=True)
print(merge_results)